# XAMPP wordpress LAN, redirect to localhost

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost, lan

I cant access my local site installed on pc from other device.
If i put 192.168.x.x, is loading 192.168.x.x/dashboard. The same for lan. its good.
Putting 192.168.x.x/site will be loaded my wordpress site for local pc without problems, but will redirect to localhost/site for lan devices! Why??
No hosts modified, no xampp files modified. In wordpress settings, the urls (2) are setted as 192.168.x.x/site
Restart apache does not help.
What happens?

Edit0:
I have modified one thing:
httpd.conf, Listen 192.168.x.x:80

Edit1:
I added new folder 'test' and 'index.html' with 'TEST' text. Is working, i can access from any device with 192.168.x.x/test. So, is some problem with wordpress? I will try to install wordpress again, to new folder.

Solution: reinstall wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows OS, first of all, check your sharing settings:
`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings`.

Make your network discoverable. If you don't know which type of network you are using you can find it from here: `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center > View your active networks`.

If you couldn't find that, choose "Turn on network discoverable" for all of them but please note that this is an unsecured way.

Then use ping command from other devices to check that your local PC is reachable.
If your PC was reachable from other devices, then you can open your local-website by opening your local IP address:
`http://192.168.x.x`

You can use these configurations for your Apache:
`Listen 192.168.x.x:80` OR
`Listen 80` OR
`Listen 0.0.0.0:80`